# Linux lsblk -f and alike command inside chroot is ineffectual

Tags: chroot

Why Linux lsblk -f or alike command inside chroot cannot show what it was as supposed to be, how is the snippet/script to fix it, also to make most CLI behaviors outside chroot will work inside it too ?

## lsblk -f

..

Comment: "make most CLI behaviors work in chroot" - that's way too broad to be answerable. Also not much of a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Anyway, you can look at what's failing using `strace`, it's probably trying to read some filesystem like /sys which is not accessible inside your chroot.